# How to take Unicode characters as UserName in ASP.NET Core Mvc?

Tags: c#, unicode, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

In my ASP.NET Core app I want to take UserName from other language than English but when I try to create an user I got the error

`"User name 'myUnicodeLang' is invalid, can only contain letters or digits."`

How can I allow Unicode characters for my `UserManager`? I found a question that how to take email as UserName and the solution was.

```
UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager) 
{ 
    AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false 
};
```

but it's not working in my project it says `Using the Generic Type UserManager<TUser> requires 1 type argument`

#Edit

Controller Constructor

```
public AuthController(UserManager<SchoolUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<SchoolUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;

        //Error here
        UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<SchoolUser>
        (userManager) 
         { 
           AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
         }
     }
```

Comment: .NET strings *are* Unicode. That's not what the error says though. It says the validation rules for login names allow only latin letters and digits.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos, Yes I know that but how do I set custom validation?

Comment: User *logins* aren't  user names on the other hand. Imagine trying to login into a web site from abroad if the machine you use doesn't have the appropriate keybard

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos, Imagine it will be only use in a fixed region then How I do it?

Comment: you already found how. The syntax error complains about an actual error - in the call to `new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager)` you are supposed to pass an actual UserManager instance, not a type name

Comment: `UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<SchoolUser>(userManager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };` still same error

Comment: *Where* do you call that? Post the code, not parts of it. This call should be made *inside* the `AccountsController` constructor, which provides the manager as a parameter. You shouldn't have to create a *new* validator, just set the property of the existing one. And `SchoolUser` isn't `ApplicationUser`. *Don't* try random things, create a new ASP.NET Core MVC application and simply change the validator in the AccountsController constructor

Comment: Please see my edited question

Comment: the code you posted is for ASP.NET MVC, not ASP.NET *Core* MVC. Even in the previous MVC framework it wouldn't have workd. You tried to do is assing a validator using syntax that only works for static classes

Comment: I didn't found any solution for asp.net core, I mentioned ASP.NET Core in my question and tag. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question looks like an attempt to add ASP.NET MVC code into a Core MVC project. That won't work because in ASP.NET Core MVC the UserManager *doesn't* have a UserValidator property. It has a `UserValidators` collection that allows adding multiple custom validators.

The UserValidator has also changed and doesn't contain any configuration settings itself.

The easiest way to configure the allowable characters is to use the `AddIdentity()` overload in `Startup.ConfigureServices` that allows setting properties. Replace :

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
```

With

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options=>
{
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "whatever";
})
```

The default value is `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+"` which can handle most email addresses

You could append extra characters to this, eg:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options=>
{
    var allowed = options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters 
                  + "........";
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = allowed;
})
```

Comment: It's working,  after adding `"myUnicodes"` to the `options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters`